# VBA won't allow me to declare empty array of Integers

Tags: excel, vba

this code keeps giving me the error: "For Each may only iterate over a collection object or array." When I change the type of array to variant, the code works as intended, but I need to use integers for comparison purposes. Does anyone know what is going on here? This code has worked fine before, but started giving me this error just recently.

```
Sub Pulse_Pop_rColors()
'On Error GoTo Err
Dim lastC, lastR, n As Long
Dim findlcol As Range
Dim r, g, b, r1, g1, b1 As Integer
Dim arr() As Integer
ReDim arr(1 To 1) As Integer
With pop_frm
    r = .findR.Value
    g = .findG.Value
    b = .findB.Value
    r1 = .repR.Value
    g1 = .repG.Value
    b1 = .repB.Value
End With
lastR = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Debug.Print "poop"
With ActiveSheet
    Set findlcol = .Columns(1).Find(What:="Column %", After:=.Cells(1, 1))
End With
n = findlcol.Row
lastC = Cells(n, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Debug.Print (lastC)
Debug.Print (lastR)
For ro = 1 To lastR
    If Cells(ro, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(r, g, b) Then
        Cells(ro, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(r1, g1, b1)
        arr(UBound(arr)) = ro
        ReDim Preserve arr(1 To UBound(arr) + 1) As Integer
        Debug.Print ro
    End If
Next ro
For Each x In arr(UBound(arr) - 1)
    If x > 0 Then
        Range(Cells(x, 2), Cells(x, lastC)).Interior.Color = RGB(r1, g1, b1)
    End If
Next x
```

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/129931

Comment: `arr(UBound(arr) - 1)` will return a single number, so you're running the equivalent of (for example) `For Each x In 15` which may not be what you wanted to do.

Comment: I'm sceptical that "this code has worked fine before" and "when I change the type of array to variant, the code works as intended".  Do you have the version of the code that *does* work with the array declared as `Variant`?

Comment: yeah, nevermind, Tim Williams answered my question. I'm not really sure how it worked before, but it did...I stopped using For Each and used a For Next and it now works just fine without having to declare arr as a variant.